# Gerar arquivo XML de mais de 1 Mi de registros com Xml.etree.elementtree no python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, pandas, numpy

Por favor, como posso gerar uma arquivo XML, com Xml.etree.elementtree no python, mas de forma que o mesmo crie o arquivo de 5 mil em 5 mil resgitros, sem a necessidade de esperear carregar o recordset inteiro.

1. O dados são extraidos do DB PostgreSQL com Pandas e Numpy.
2. O que eu fiz até o momento, esta funcinado, mas sem a geração
   parcial, conforme descrito acima.

**Código:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from datetime import datetime

def main(query):
    df = np.array(pd.read_sql(query, engine))
    gerar_xml(df)

def gerar_xml(rs):
    add = ET.Element('add')

    for i in rs:
        doc = ET.Element('doc', abc='' + str(var) + '')
        ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='id').text = str(i[0])
        ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='cc').text = str(i[1])
        ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='db').text = str(i[2])

        ...
            Diversos campos e if para controle de outro elementos
        ...

        add.append(doc)

    arquivo = ET.ElementTree(add)
    arquivo.write('Name.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pwd@Server:PORT/Base')

    query = "select * from table"

    main(query)
```

Comment: (agora sim :-)  - só vai dar um trabalhinho tecer umas considerações aí - mas a gente dá um jeito)

Comment: :-) vlw @jsbueno!
E sim, seu que vou ter uma trabalha, mas estou meio perdido de por onde começar.

Answer (score 0):

Então - da forma como você está fazendo, há duas coisas que precisam de todos os registros na memória ao mesmo tempo - uma delas é o Pandas - ele vai ler todos os seus registros do banco e criar um dataframe com todos os dados na memória no formato usado pelo Python.

Se você realmente estivesse usando alguma das características do Pandas, teriamos que paginar a leitura do banco (com a cláusula `LIMIT` na query), e criar dataframes parciais - se algum resultado do Pandas dependesse de todos os registros, teriamos que pensar em estratégias de agrupar isso, etc... (mas veja o projeto [Dask](https://dask.org/) se precisar de algo assim).

Se você quiser criar um único arquivo XML com todo o 1 milhão de registros, aí temos que abordar o segundo "vilão" - como o XML tem um elemento que é "pai" de todos os outros (o elemento "add", no caso), seria o caso de escrever as linhas de abertura desse elemento manualmente no arquiv de saída, escrever os blocos desejados, e escrever manualmente  o `</add>` ao final do arquivo. Não é difícil fazer - mas seriam uns 10-15 minutos se eu fosse escrever tudo aqui.

Já, para gerar vários arquivos XML, cada um com 5 mil registros, a coisa é bem mais simples - é só associar um contador na sua função de saída, e criar um arquivo novo toda vez que o limite for atingido:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy
from datetime import datetime

RECORDS_PER_FILE = 5000

def main(query):
    # Não é necessário carregar a query toda para um  dataframe
    # df = np.array(pd.read_sql(query, engine))
    gerar_xml(query)

def write_xml(element, num):
    arquivo = ET.ElementTree(element)
    arquivo.write(f'Name{num:03d}.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)

def gerar_xml(records):
    add = None
    file_num = 0

    # voce nao ganha nada de chamar a variavel do for de "i" - 
    # deixe um nome que representa o que ela é. "i" é usado em linguagens
    # que só tem for numérico, e dentro do for você precisa recuperar o
    # objeto
    for index, record in enumerate(records):
        if index % RECORDS_PER_FILE == 0:
            if add:
                write_xml(add, file_num)
                file_num += 1
            add = ET.Element('add')
        # o seu código não mostra de onde veio 'var'. De qualquer forma
        # "somar" strings para compor uma string maior é hábito de javasctipr
        # que não tem muitos métodos para strings. Em Python,
        # use "f-strings". E mesmo assim, somar strings vazias é uma "não operação": não faz nada
        doc = ET.Element('doc', abc='' + str(var) + '')
        ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='id').text = str(record[0])
        ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='cc').text = str(record[1])
        ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='db').text = str(record[2])

        ...
            Diversos campos e if para controle de outro elementos
        ...

        add.append(doc)

    # Escreve os registros finais
    write_xml(add, file_num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:pwd@Server:PORT/Base')

    query = "select * from table"

    main(query)
```

Mas a boa notícia é que, como você nao está usando nada do Pandas, apenas iterando os registros, a query do Postgres que você usa já faz isso -

Comment: Entendi @jsbueno, vou fazer mais algumas tentativas aqui. Obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia amigo!

Você pode criar um contador e alterar a função gerar_xml() para receber o nome do arquivo a ser gerado, o índice inicial e o número de registros a serem processados de cada vez para gerar diversos arquivos XML.

**Por exemplo:**

```
def gerar_xml(rs, nome_arquivo, indice_inicial, num_registros):
    add = ET.Element('add')

    # Loop para processar os registros em blocos de tamanho num_registros
    for i in range(indice_inicial, len(rs), num_registros):
        # Criar um subconjunto dos registros a serem processados neste bloco
        bloco = rs[i:i+num_registros]
        # Loop para processar cada registro no bloco
        for r in bloco:
            doc = ET.Element('doc', abc='' + str(var) + '')
            ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='id').text = str(r[0])
            ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='cc').text = str(r[1])
            ET.SubElement(doc, 'field', name='db').text = str(r[2])
            # Outros campos e lógica de controle aqui
            add.append(doc)

        # Gerar o arquivo XML para o bloco atual
        arquivo = ET.ElementTree(add)
        arquivo.write(f'{nome_arquivo}_{i//num_registros}.xml', encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
        # Limpar o elemento 'add' para o próximo bloco
        add.clear()
```

Com essa modificação, a função irá processar os registros em blocos de tamanho num_registros, criando um arquivo XML para cada bloco. O nome do arquivo é determinado pelo parâmetro nome_arquivo e pelo índice do bloco `(i//num_registros)`.

Para chamar essa função na função main(), você pode fazer algo como:

```
def main(query):
    df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
    rs = df.to_numpy()
    gerar_xml(rs, 'meu_arquivo', 0, 5_000)
```

Neste exemplo, o parâmetro num_registros é definido como 5_000, ou seja, a função irá processar 5 mil registros por bloco. O índice inicial é zero, indicando que a função irá começar a processar os registros a partir do primeiro.

Com isso, a função irá gerar vários arquivos XML, cada um com 5 mil registros, até processar todos os registros.

Comment: Obrigado @Obama, vou tentar outas possibilidades!
Desculpa a demora, estava ausente da ferramenta!